# How to move a child element above another child element of a parent element that is above it's own parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have two parent elements (a black and red `div`s). Each of them contain a child element. The black one contains a gray div. The red one contains a pink div.

Following constraints:

- I can not change the relationship between child to it's own parent element, i.e. I can not move a child element outside of it's own parent element.
- The red div has to remain underneath the black div

Is it possible to move the pink div above the gray div?

```css
.parent-black {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  color: white
}

.child-gray {
  width: 250px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 137px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

.parent-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: -999;
}

.child-pink {
  width: 95%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-red">
  2
  <div class="child-pink">2.1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent-black">
  1
  <div class="child-gray">1.1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does underneath mean lower z-index or positioning?

Comment: Well if you remove the z index on the parent-red the pink will be above gray.

Comment: @Ihazkode the black div has to cover the red div, i.e. the red div "hides" below the black div. That's what I meant with "underneath the black div"

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child-gray').insertBefore($('.child-pink'));
})
```

```css
.parent-black {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  color: white
}

.child-gray {
  width: 250px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 137px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

.parent-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: -999;
}

.child-pink {
  width: 95%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-red">
  2
  <div class="child-pink">2.1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent-black">
  1
  <div class="child-gray">1.1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't get the *real* problem here... I guess this follows your constraints:

```css
.parent-black {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.child-gray {
  width: 250px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 137px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

.parent-red {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.child-pink {
  width: 95%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 70px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-black">
  1
  <div class="child-gray">1.1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent-red">
  2
  <div class="child-pink">2.1</div>
</div>
```